# Get decimal places for a double value

Tags: .net, double, scientific-notation

I'm working with VB.NET:

I'm looking for a function which gets the number of decimal places for a double value.

I already have a function which does this for values like "0.01", but not for values like "1E-6", but that's what I need.

There is a similar (answered) question on StackOverflow, but doesn't work for scientific notation:
[Decimal places in a number in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947333/decimal-places-in-a-number-on-vb-net)

Required function:

```
Input: 0.001 / Output: 3
Input: 0.000001 (.ToString() representation: "1E-6") / Output: 5
```

Have anyone an elegant way (VB.NET/C#)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function should do it:

```
    Public Function GetDecimalPlaces(ByVal Value As Double, ByVal Culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Integer
        Dim val As String = String.Empty
        Dim valSplitted As String() = Nothing

        Try
            val = Value.ToString("0.######################")

            valSplitted = val.Split(CChar(Culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator))
            If (valSplitted.Length = 1) Then Return 0

            Return valSplitted(1).Length
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
```